# Why does "'lo' insulté y 'le' ordené que me siguiera" use direct object and indirect object pronouns?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos

This is a sentence from "La Forma de la Espada", by Borges:

> Entonces yo volví, derribé de un golpe al soldado, sacudí a Vincent Moon, **lo** insulté y **le** ordené que me siguiera.

I think I understand the theory of direct/indirect pronouns, but I don't understand the usage in this sentence. Why is Vincent Moon the direct object in "**lo** insulté", but then the indirect object in "**le** ordené".

Comment: Handy ["cheat sheet"](http://www.rae.es/consultas/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo) for pronouns, leísmo, laísmo, loísmo

Answer (score 5):

That's because with the verb *ordenar* the direct object is the given order, and the indirect object is the recipient of that order. With *insultar* you have only a direct object, the one receiving the insult.

Comment: Great answer. In case it helps to clarify: In "**le** ordené (a Moon) que me siguiera" "le" refers to Moon. If it was "**lo** ordené" the "lo" would refer to the order given.

Comment: Oh, this is a new concept for me. I need to figure this out better.

Comment: I'm not clear about the distinction between these two verbs. They are both intransitive. Don't both have to have a direct object? Are you saying that the verb is the direct object, also?

Comment: @AndaBien both verbs are *transitive*, meaning they both take a direct object. The difference is that *ordenar* also takes an indirect object.

Comment: @AndaBien "que me siguiera" is the direct object for *ordenar*.

Comment: @rsanchez, oops, I meant transitive. My bad.
I think I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The direct complement can be sometimes preceded by the preposition `a`, like in the case of your example:

> insulté a Vicente = lo insulté

This happens when the direct object is animate, like a person:

> Vi a tu hermano = lo vi
>
> Vi tu carro = lo vi

Check RAE's "Nueva gramática de la lengua española" *34.8 El complemento directo preposicional (I). Nombres y pronombres. Complementos de persona* for a thorough explanation.